# JMeter 5.3 doesn't respond after a click File->Open File on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: macos, jmeter

For a few days I cannot open any JMX file in JMeter script. Even after click File->Recently Opened, JMeter opens this file but non of click action on this file doesn't work. I am using JMeter version 5.3.

What I've done:

- tried to used another JMeter version (5.5)
- unistalled and installed newest JDK version (17.0.4.1)
- upgraded all MacOS upgraded
- scanned my MACOS in order to find a viruses
- opened another applications based on Java and try to open the file (f.e. Intelij)
- Increased Heap from 256M to 512M
- Killed all denudant processes
- Opened the java logs

All these actions were unsuccessful. Slowly my ideas are ran-down. Any idea from you what else can I check?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

so most probably something is wrong with your Java/JMeter/OS/user/whatever.

You can try following troubleshooting steps:

1. [Increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to maximum and see whether there are any suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
2. Check your OS logs using [Console](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac) application
3. Try switching to another Look and Feel via Options -> Look and Feel. If this doesn't work as well you can do it using [command line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config) i.e.

   ```
   ./jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
   ```
4. Try running JMeter and providing the path to the .jmx script via [-t command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   ./jmeter -t /path/to/test.jmx
   ```